# Programmatic WebBrowser scrolling

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible to somehow programmatically scroll WebBrowser Silverlight control?

```
        <WebBrowser
        x:Name="BrowserControll"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Margin="10,10,10,0"
        Source="http://www.google.com" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`WebBrowser.InvokeScript()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), and pass in some javascript that will scroll the browser to the desired location.  See the [`window.scrollTo()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp) javascript method.

For example:

```
BrowserControl.InvokeScript("window.scrollTo(0,100)");
```

Would scroll the browser 100 pixels down.